# Передавать данные скрипта из страницы на страницу

Tags: javascript

У меня есть статичный сайт. Никаких пхп и всё такое.
И я подумал, что было бы клёво, если бы, например, при посещении сайта какая-то информация бы хранилась "как будто бы в кеше".

Вот например: есть блог. Человек заходит на сайт. Щелкает на записи блога, текст поста открывается-закрывается.
А на сайте работает скрипт, что просмотренные записи помечаются, к примеру, красным.
И вот интересно было бы, если бы человек просто нажал на переход на следующую страницу блога (будем считать, что всё происходит в одном домене), пощёлкал там, а затем вернулся на предыдущую, и те записи вновь красные!
То есть, как я понимаю, для такого и нужна передача данных со страницы на страницу.

Никаких пхп и баз данных.
Ничего страшного, что после сеанса и при потери кеша записи не будут помечаться.
"Срок годности" эффекта вполне устроит до тех пор, пока на вкладке не был совершен переход на другие сайты.

---

Естественно, первое и единственное, что пришло мне в голову, это get-запросы.
Но тут есть нюансик, что мне не нравится искорёженный этим способом url.
В принципе-то против этого способа ничего не имею. Берем url и делаем регулярку, парсим строку - всё круто.  Если бы был способ избежать этот негативный эффект... Или можно? То как?
Или всё-таки есть более выгодный вариант, о котором я не догадываюсь? Однако если такового не существует - уточните. Мне интересно (:

Comment: `localStorage`/`sessionStorage` -  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: @Igor ну вот, этого я даже  и  не думал) Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день!

Ваши варианты:

1. Храним в URL (всё как вы и описали)
2. Храним на сервере. Проблемы: вычисление "уникальности" пользователя,
   нужна БД и прочее
3. Храним в печеньках - cookie. Проблемы: размер, сложности с доступом, может быть отключено
4. Храним в localStorage. Проблемы: размер (зависит от браузера), может быть недоступно

Как и @Igor я бы посоветовал вам вариант с localStorage. Он простой и удобный. Примеры тут: [developer.mozilla.org localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Спасибо, подумаю. А вот этот вариант: https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie Это и есть "хранение в куках"? Я просто не знал, что через js есть к ним доступ. Не работал с ними никогда.

Comment: Да, это оно, но локальное хранилище в разы проще - просто ключ/значение и положить можно всё что хотите :-) Можно json или даже html там хранить. Его кстати многие сайты используют :-)

Comment: Неплохо. Тогда посмотрю в его сторону, спасибо.